# How do you search a vector with hashed names for a match?

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm, vector, hash

So my professor assigned this project for us. It's pretty simple because it's our first hashing program. The program is to take 15 names as input and hash them and store them in something. I did it in a vector. Now once they are hashed the user enters another name and it will should hash that name and try to match it to one in the vector. Maybe it is me or maybe it is how he wrote the question but I'm a little confused. Our program is suppose to have collision protection. Which means we run an algorithm on the name inputted and it will spit out a number and that number is where we store the name in the vector. If there is another name already in that spot we are suppose to store it in the next available spot.

So lets say I enter the name jordan and jon. The algorithm will tell me to store these in the same spot (lets say spot 8) but collision protection will recognize that jordan is already taking up the spot (8) and it will move jon to the next available spot(lets say spot 9). Now when the user is entering names to see if it is in the vector already and he enters jon, the algorithm will see it should be in spot 8. Do you think I should just check to see if that spot is empty, if not say a match has been found in spot 8, even though the name in spot 8 is jordan and the name entered is jon. Or should I start at spot 8 and see if the strings match, and if they don't check the next spot and so on until i return to the original spot or find the match?

I wrote the program and it works fine, I just ran into this one dilemma and can't finish the program.  Thanks

Comment: Once you find the slot in your hash table where `jordan` hashes to, walk the collision list (which may be empty) looking for a matching entry *using value comparison*. if no such entry exists, add him to the collision list for that hash table slot. Repeat the algorithm for `jon`. In other words, the "Or should I..." closure of your second paragraph would seem along the lines of what you should be doing, but it depends on what you mean by "next available slot". And code speaks *loudly*, so post it if you have concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is [Open Addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) collision handling.

According to this approach, when you are searching for an element, you should 'keep going' until you find the first empty spot - only then you are guaranteed the requested element is not stored.

Answer (score 1):

Three things can happen when you look up a value.

1. You find the value you're looking for.
2. You find an empty spot in your hash table.
3. You find some other value in the assigned spot you're looking at.

In cases 1 and 2, it's clear what you should do. You know for sure that the value you're looking for is either in your table or it's not. In the third case, you should follow the same procedure that you do when adding items to the table. That is, keep looking in the next spot until you reach either condition 1 or 2 above.